# Как сделать широкий текстовый курсор в input type=text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно зделать широкий текстовый курсор в `input type=text` и чтобы при перемещении его назад он становился под буквой, а та окрашивалась в контрастный цвет. Интернет весь перерыл, сам наделал кучу полурабочих костылей. Теперь пишу сюда, может кто-то с подобной проблемой сталкивался и терпения у него было по более... Можно и с `jQuery`, мне уже фиолетово да и времени нет...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно картинку того что хотите сделать?

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: Нужно типа такого, только на JavaScript.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, режим, в который почти все текстовые редакторы переключаются при нажатии insert. И ненавижу скайп - он переключается, но никак об этом не говорит...

Comment: @Qwertiy ???????????????????????????

Comment: @Qwertiy ииии что?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, см. ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy по-моему автор всё-таки хочет не режим, а просто стилизованный курсор. Во многих терминалах такой

Comment: @andreymal, стилизованный курсор без режима - это жесть. Тогда уж надо стилизовать под подчёркивание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал решение сам, может кому пригодится:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('text');
var wrp = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrp.onclick = function() {
  txt.focus();
}

setInterval(function() {
  var pos = getCursorPosition(txt);
  var val = txt.value;
  var symb;
  if (typeof val[pos] == "undefined" || val[pos] == " ") symb = "&nbsp;";
  else symb = val[pos];
  var curs = "<span style='background: #000; color: #fff;'>" + symb + "</span>";
  var p1 = val.slice(0, pos);
  var p2 = val.slice(pos + 1, val.lenght);
  wrp.innerHTML = p1.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;") + curs + p2.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");

  wrp.style.top = (txt.getBoundingClientRect().top + txt.offsetTop + 3) + "px";
  wrp.style.left = (txt.getBoundingClientRect().left + txt.offsetLeft + 2) + "px";

  txt.style.width = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(wrp).width, 10) + 10 + "px";
}, 10);

function getCursorPosition(ctrl) {
  var caretPos = 0;
  if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
    caretPos = sel.text.length;
  } else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0') {
    caretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
  }
  return caretPos;
}
```

```css
#text {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: transparent;
}

#wrapper {
  font-family: monospace;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
<span id="wrapper"></span>
```

Comment: 1. `(txt.getBoundingClientRect().top + txt.offsetTop + 3)` - в этих формулах ошибка. 2. Введи в input `a<b`. 3. setInterval(..., 10) - это жесть. 4. Нажми Ctrl+A.

Comment: @Qwertie, у меня всё пашит, и при выделении курсор едет в начало. Мне так и нужно. Меня моё решение устраивает, ведь другого нет.

Comment: @Qwertie, а по поводу `a<b` просто заменить на html-сущность и всё.

Comment: 0. А можно ник правильно писать? 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVblb.png - неровно же. 3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha6Ul.png - оба текста видимы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, прошу прощения за опечатку в нике. У меня ровно. На мобильном устройстве. На компе не смотрлел.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так (надо бы проверку на всякие модификаторы добавить):

```js
function updateSelection(event) {
  var inp = event.target;
  
  if (inp.selectionStart === inp.selectionEnd) {
    ++inp.selectionEnd;
  }
}

var inp = document.querySelector('input');

inp.addEventListener('input', updateSelection);
inp.addEventListener('keyup', updateSelection);
inp.addEventListener('click', updateSelection);

inp.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  var inp = event.target;

  if (event.keyCode === 37 && inp.selectionStart+1 === inp.selectionEnd) { // Left
    --inp.selectionEnd;
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  font-family: monospace;
}

::selection {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: классно, но работает как инсерт

Comment: а должен  наоборот

Comment: я так думаю....

Comment: @Duoxx, почему? Я наоборот понял, что так и надо. Обычно без insert курсор - это просто подчёркивание, а с insert - инвертирование буквы.

Comment: хорошо, а как насчет курсора в конце который не широкий,я смотрел делают костыли с дивами.

Comment: Qwertiy, нет, это просто какой-то счётчик? Я делал через эмуляцию дополнительного span, но не шибко получилось.

Comment: @Евгений, не понял, к чему относится "нет". По поводу курсора в конце - можно пробел добавлять.

Comment: @Qwertiy, он работает, но цвет я должен контролировать или, хотябы чтобы он был как у текста (как на картинке).

Comment: @Qwertiy, оно должно работать на мобильном устройстве.

Comment: @Qwertie, фон не работает в андроид браузере.